# How do I get the user's Operating System in a TMS Web Core Website?

Tags: delphi, operating-system, tms-web-core

I'd like to know what operating system (Windows, MacOS, Linux, Android, iOS, etc.) the user has on his computer.

In FMX, I could simply do `TOSVersion.ToString` from `System.SysUtils` to get the operating system, but in TMS Web Core it doesn't work. I get the following error:

> [Error] identifier not found "TOSVersion"

How can I check or get the operating system with Delphi in TMS Web Core?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
function GetOperatingSystem(): String;
var
  UserAgent: String;
begin
  UserAgent := window.navigator.userAgent;
  Result := 'Unknown';
  if (UserAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 10.0') <> -1) then Result := 'Windows 10'
  else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 6.2') <> -1) then Result := 'Windows 8'
  else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 6.1') <> -1) then Result := 'Windows 7'
  else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 6.0') <> -1) then Result := 'Windows Vista'
  else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 5.1') <> -1) then Result := 'Windows XP'
  else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 5.0') <> -1) then Result := 'Windows 2000'
  else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Windows Phone') <> -1) then Result := 'Windows 10 Mobile'
  else if (UserAgent.indexOf('iPhone') <> -1) then Result := 'iOS'
  else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Mac') <> -1) then Result := 'MacOS'
  else if (UserAgent.indexOf('AppleTV') <> -1) then Result := 'tvOS'
  else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Android') <> -1) then Result := 'Android'
  else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Linux') <> -1) then Result := 'Linux'
  else if (UserAgent.indexOf('X11') <> -1) then Result := 'UNIX';
end;
```

But note that this isn't always 100% accurate. The userAgent can be changed by the browser or via code. It is also detecting Windows 11 as Windows 10.

---

There is however a spec proposal that aims to help with the above issues: https://wicg.github.io/ua-client-hints/

---

There is also [this (detectOS.js)](https://github.com/1000tech/detectOS.js) JavaScript library that you could possibly use for detecting the operating system.

Comment: This is also very inefficient - why not searching for `Windows NT ` just once instead of 6 times? Only when found you then look at the version number. You'll also mistake _iOS_ for _MacOS_ and _Android_ for plain _Linux_, while _X11_ is also used on _Linux_. You don't even connect every condition with `else` - even if it has been found the other checks are still performed!

Comment: @AmigoJack Thanks for the feedback. I've improved the function. It now detects a better variety of operating systems and I'm using `else` for the if statements.